# Combobox c# SelectedItem not work

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem, selectedindex

I am a junior on C#. I have problem with Combobox. When I using SelectedItem is no working exactly, what I want. SelectedItem always return the last item in combobox, but when I using SelectedIndex is return correct result.

Example in combobox is 3 items: Admin, Moderation, Salesman. Is always return Salesman, when I using SelectedItem, even when I select Admin.

There is my code:

class ComboboxItem

```
    class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

add items into combobox

```
        private void AddItemIntoComboBoxGroup()
    {
        string query = "SELECT* FROM kites_mango.staff_group; ";
        DBUtility data = new DBUtility();
        List<string>[] list = data.Select(query);

        if (list != null && list[0].Count() > 0)
        {
            ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count(); i++)
            {
                item.Value = list[0][i];
                item.Text = (list[1][i] + " - " + list[0][i]);
                CbBGroup.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

get selected item

```
            if (CbBGroup.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(CbBGroup.SelectedIndex + "/" + CbBGroup.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Are you using SelectedIndexChanged event to get selected item?

Comment: No, I dont using it...

Comment: Then at what event are you getting the value of SelectedItem?

Comment: In the button Save event click

Answer (score 1):

You're instancing the *ComboboxItem* object before the for loop. This way, for each loop in your *for* statement, you're changing the properties of the same object, making objects that were loaded before in the list are also modified. That is, your list could have 3 itens, but they are going to have the same value (Salesman) because all the itens in your list have the same object reference.

Just change from this:

```
        ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count(); i++)
        {
            item.Value = list[0][i];
            item.Text = (list[1][i] + " - " + list[0][i]);
            CbBGroup.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

To this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count(); i++)
        {
            ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Value = list[0][i];
            item.Text = (list[1][i] + " - " + list[0][i]);
            CbBGroup.Items.Add(item);
        }
```